# Java regex getting surrounding text extremely slow

Tags: java, regex

I am currently using java regex matching to look through a very large number of files, and locate all files that match the pattern. I want to be able to show the matching text in context, so the regex pattern I am using is:

```
[\\S|\\s]{0,30}abc[\\S|\\s]{0,30}
```

This successfully grabs "abc" as well as  up to 30 of any characters on either side.

However, when running this search through my large database of files, the search takes 21 minutes to complete (while removing the padding and searching for just "abc" makes it run in <1 minute).

Is there a reason that my regex runs so slowly? Is there a more efficient way to grab the context?

---

*NOTE: I am just using java.util.regex.Matcher and java.util.regex.Pattern in a loop over each file. I can create a short mockup of the relevant code if needed, though*

Comment: Wouldn't `[\S|\s]` be equivalent to `.`?

Comment: My understanding is that `.` matches anything except newlines, and ideally I wanted my context match to read past newlines (if the newline was within 30 chars)

Comment: You can use the [`DOTALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) flag to match newlines.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this - DOTALL did simplify & somewhat speed up my code

Comment: Alternatively, often the answer is a regular expression is not the answer. In this case, it is likely faster to simply use `String.indexOf` to find the position of the search term and then get a substring starting 30 characters before/after that.

Comment: I think this is what I'll end up doing, as even ideal regex seems much too slow for my use. Thank you for the help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `[\\S|\\s]`, it's a bit smarter to use `Pattern.DOTALL` to make `.` match anything. (or just use `(?s).{0,30}abc.{0,30}` - `(?s)` turns the DOTALL flag on from within the regexp.

Your basic regular expression can be translated to a [Thompson's Construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction) which means you are guaranteed a performance of `O(n+m)` where n stands for the length of your regexp and m for the length of your input. The input is large, but at least it's a linear growth curve. However, TCs do not support backrefs and there are a few other more exotic reasons why most regexp engines don't actually apply TC conversion. As far as I know, java's regex engine doesn't do it either, which means that **regular expressions are technically performance unbounded** - you can write a regexp that takes years to resolve. Trivially, there exists a regex that does prime number calculation (matches if the input is a prime number of `x`, fails if it is anything else). This trivially proves that regex engines can take a very long time to do their work. This regex uses backrefs, thus why it doesn't "disprove" that TC conversion *can* guarantee speedy evalulation of regexes.

Point is: Regexes can be slow if TCs aren't built, and java's regex engine does not build them.

`[\\S|\\s]{0,30}` is particularly egregious, adding quite a few complications; you're causing a combinatory explosion of different tries for that regex engine to work through. A TC construction can do it quickly, but as we established, java doesn't do that.

I bet if you just use DOTALL mode, it'll be speedy again.

Comment: DOTALL dropped runtime from 21 to 15 minutes - which is an improvement, albeit still too slow for my use. Thank you for the thorough explanation, though!

Do you know of any (reasonable-difficulty) methods of further decreasing runtime? If `.` with DOTALL is the best I can do, I'll just give up on my program doing this for now & flag this response as the accepted answer

Comment: A real simple way is to just use `.find()` on the search itself (without the `{0,30}` stuff around it), and then use basic .substring to grab the 0-30 before and after it. Alternatively, select `.{30}search.{30}`, and add additional code to do the `.{0,30}` version but only on the first X and last X characters, X being 30+search len.